# How can I add object to the page dynamically?

Tags: android, mobile, smartface.io

I try to add my objects to the `Page1` dynamically. I know how I can create them but the problem is adding them to the page.

Here is my code sample:

```
var createButton = new SMF.UI.Image();
    createButton.image = "answer.png";
    createButton.top = 5;
    createButton.width = 38;
    createButton.height = 38;
    createButton.left = 5;
    createButton.imageFillType = SMF.UI.ImageFillType.aspectFit;
    createButton.onShow = function(e) {
        alert("object created");
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. Like other programming language just use `add` method. You have to give a parameter which is your obect. Take a look below.

```
Pages.Page1.add(createButton);
```

Comment: it worked thank you. i am a beginner sir so i will need some help to learn something about mobile development and programming.